# Unable to extend desktop with USB display adapter and libdlo

Tags: debian, xfce, libraries, desktop, display-settings

Anyone familiar with using **libdlo** for DisplayLink's USB display adapters?

I've followed the instruction steps from README file of libdlo

```
 Install a compatible libusb version (0.13)
  $ ./configure
  $ sudo make install
  $ make check
```

and after the last command (make check) I've seen various testing screens which ended at this one:

[image: last test screen of libdlo's make check]

But I have no idea what to do next. How do I start using this additional screen in order to extend my desktop? I can't detect it in Display settings. I'm using Debian with xfce desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need libdlo for this. libdlo is experimental and for demonstration only.

There are some efforts to support displaylink chips directly in the kernel. According to my research (I spent about 2 weeks on this problem), desktop expansion has not yet been achieved. However, you can run a separate X11 server on the display, supported natively by the kernel, without libdlo.

I wrote a blog post about this here. The working instructions are too long to be included here, so I'm just sharing the link:

https://blog.michael.franzl.name/2012/07/28/dual-monitor-multi-seat-setup-displaylink-usb-montors/

Comment: @michael-franiz The link you provided is dead.  Do you have an updated response for 2018?  I am looking for a way to control multiple USB monitors using Debian.